# Firebase user data persistence even after logging out

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

**Goal**: Learning to make a *chat application* in Firebase. Reference Source

**Status**: Basic chat functionality completed. Used google provider for Sign-In and used the corresponding username while chatting. **Works** except for given problem situations.

***Edit 1***: All the problems mentioned below can be verified in the minimal,complete and verifiable example link given at the end. The code for chat is taken from the firebase docs - https://www.firebase.com/tutorial/#session/iq2koybqhgq with required modifications for google sign-in.

**Problem 1**: Used `unAuth()` for logging out. This kills the session( checked by going into Resources-Local Storage in Chrome browser.)

*But even after logging out* and continuing to chat it pushes data(text message with username) into Firebase storage.

**Concern and Thoughts**:In the code given below, after logging out, console has "Client unauthenticated" message which is expected behavior. Also `authData` should have the value `null` and therefore the corresponding `if` block shouldn't be executed. But in this case it is!

**Problem 2**: *After logging out* and again *logging in* I am getting double instances of the pushed data and also same amount of blank text with the username.

For example, if username is XYZ and text message is "Hi", after the said procedure above, in the chat box there are two instances of "Hi" along with XYZ(and sometimes any other username who is logged in) and also two instances of XYZ with null text message.

**Concern and Thoughts**: I think its signing-in multiple times which is causing the problem. Also this maybe due to the way data is stored(asynchronously).

**Code**:

```
userRef.onAuth(function(authData) {
    if (authData) {
        //code to push the username and corresponding text message into firebase
    } else {
        console.log("Client unauthenticated.");
    }
});
```

I have checked a lot of other questions on stack but I thought these bugs specific to my code. If any further information needed please do ask.

***Edit 2***:https://jsfiddle.net/91swbfd7/5/ - **Problem 1** has been been solved by some tweaking. Still not able to solve **Problem 2**.

Comment: Most of the behavior you describe indeed indicates that you have a mistake in how you handle sign in. But it's impossible to say more without seeing a [minimal, complete that reproduces the behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). A good way might be to reproduce the problem in a jsfiddle/jsbin and then edit your question to include the relevant code from there.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes that is a good idea.. I'll do that!

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have created a jsfiddle for reference. Would you suggest AngularFire as an alternative solution? Please take a look at the fiddle mentioned in the edit above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crucial bit is:

```
userRef.onAuth(function(authData) {
  if (authData) {
    ...
    messagesRef.limitToLast(10).on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
      ...
```

So whenever the use is authenticated, you add a new listener that will keep synchronizing the last 10 messages. This means that if the user authenticates for a second time, you're adding a second listener and you'll get two `child_added` calls for each message.

There are two things missing here:

1. whenever the user is unauthenticated, you should stop listening for the `child_added` events
2. whenever the user is unauthenticated, you should also clear the messages from the HTML:

   ```
   var query;
   if (authData) {
     ...
     query = messagesRef.limitToLast(10)
     query.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
   } else {        //If client is logged out
     console.log("Client unauthenticated.");
     query.off('child_added');
     messageList.empty();
   }
   ```

Comment: I'll get back to you after implementing the changes. Thanks.

Comment: I have been able to solve the first problem. Still not able to figure out the second one - https://jsfiddle.net/91swbfd7/5/ Whenever I authenticate the user again, the query is being run multiple times. If I take the query outside the onAuth block it obviously won't work. Please provide some solution.